# Layout buckets and density confusion

Tags: android, android-layout

I've looked through [the official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) and [the blog entry](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2011/07/new-tools-for-managing-screen-sizes.html) on supporting multiple screens. Correct me if I'm wrong - this separation is all about device sizes. If so - could you elucidate why the bucket modifiers(small, normal, large, xlarge) are related to "dp" units:

> xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
>
> large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp

So, "dp" is amount of pixels on a given physical square - inch square if I'm not mistaken. Hence, isn't it possible that a handset device will ever contain amount of pixels equal to density denoted by xlarge bucket - 960dp x 720dp. I mean - if dp is converted into pixels - there might be a device with size of a handset and resolution equal to amount of pixels contained in 960dp and as a result the template that is dedicated for tablets would be picked instead of handset one.

Thanks.

Comment: right, but under handsets I mean normal smart-phones. So, if one contains the denoted amount he would render the wrong template.

Answer (score 0):

Screens are not just `big` or `small` but have be described in more physical way with use of pixels and density, so to be able to categorize any screen as `large` or `normal` you have to 'normalize' all these hardware parameters. And `dp` serves this purpose just perfect. If you just needs to know if screen is bigger than `normal` but exact pixels or density is out your interest, you use this bucked. If you care about pixels or densities, you use other modifiers. It's just matter of what you need, and it is good to be able to have so many options to choose from.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about normalization, but what also confuses me is the way documentation lays out those classifications. When I look at, say, `xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp` rule it means to me that they're interchangeable, which in turn means that a handset(smartphone) with amount of pixels corresponding to 960dp might as well apply a resource which is dedicated to a tablet. Or does it mean that the more dp you have - the more size you get ?

Answer (score 0):

The dp unit doesn't say how many pixels something is, but instead it say how many inch/mm something is.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#terms) say that you can convert dp to pixels using this formula:

```
px = dp * (dpi / 160)
```

To get dp instead of pixels you can rewrite the expression as follows:

```
dp = px / (dpi * 160)
```

If you just take a look at the units in this forula you get:

```
dp = pixels / (pixels / inch) <==> dp = (pixels / pixels) * inch
```

Here you can see that the unit for dp is actually inch. 160 dp is also about 1 inch so when you have a bucket of size 960 dp x 720 dp it's actually the same as 6 inch x 4,5 inch.

So regardless of what resolution a phone with 3 inch wide screen have the screen will stay at 3 inch and never become 6 inch, it's just the dpi of the screen that changes. So it is impossible for a phone to get put in the wrong screen size bucket.